# NSURLConnection Asynchrone delegate method not called

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I'm developing a WebService. And i'm developing my iOS client with NSURL. I send asynchronous request to server and got data (packet by packet). My request is sent to server correctly, but no delegate method are called.

```
@implementation WebServiceClientCom

...

-(void) connectionDidFinishedLoading:(NSURLConnection*) in_urlConnection
{
    int i=0;
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{
    NSLog(@"YOUPI");
    int i=0;
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{
    NSLog(@"YOUPI");
    int i=0;
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

{
    NSLog(@"YOUPI");
    int i=0;
}

-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError: (NSError*) error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    int i=0;
}

-(void) sendAsynchronousRequest: (NSData*) in_dataToSend
{
    _oUrlRequest.HTTPBody = in_dataToSend;
    _oUrlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_oUrlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    if(!_oUrlConnection)
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    else
        NSLog(@"Connection succeeded");
}

@end
```

I don't understand what is the problem? Why? Where?

Help me please :)

Comment: Are you making sure to set the delegate?  Show us your code to create the `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: how is _oUrlConnection defined?

Comment: Do you declare that you implement `NSURLConnectionDelegate` interface?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but you should take a look at `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data,
NSError *connectionError))handler`

Comment: Are you keeping a strong reference to the WebServiceClientCom instance that you are using?.

Comment: Yes after my send, i've "while" loop for waiting delegate method call

Comment: "Unrelated to your issue but you should take a look at + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError))handler"

Thanks ToddB, but i want to get data packet by packet, relative to data receiving progressively.

PS: Server send to Client big file >500Mo. So in my client, i want to minimize my buffer size, i prefer getting data packet by packet and save directly in file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the delegate, make sure you do not pass nil as parameter:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

for more information take a look at [using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
_oUrlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_oUrlRequest delegate:self  startImmediately:NO];
[_oUrlConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[_oUrlConnection start];
```

Maybe it is being executed in another thread.

Comment: The code in the question shows that this is already being done.

Comment: Since the delegate is a weak reference, anything else holding a strong reference to self?

Comment: No i'm not forgot that: _oUrlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_oUrlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; PS: _oUrlConnection is a (NSURLConnection*) type member of my class WebServiceClientCom _oUrlRequest is a (NSURLRequest*) type member of my class WebServiceClientCom and previously initialized My code looks like each code that we can found in the Internet but doesn't run :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you are not holding a strong reference to your `WebServiceClientCom` object, it could be thrown out before you receive a response. Try this where you're using this class instance instead:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (strong) WebServiceClientCom *myCommunicator;
/* ... */
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)communicate:(NSData *)data {
  if (!self.myCommunicator) {
    self.myCommunicator = [[WebServiceClientCom alloc] init];
  }
  [self.myCommunicator sendAsynchronousRequest:data];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks Ian but i do that:

@interface WebServiceClientManager

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thansk all, I just forgot `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` after my connection `[[NSURLConnection alloc] intiWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES]`

But, I've got another problem: How can i quit this loop and so the asynchronous method??? ^^